# Position iframe content above all content

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I need to display an iframe when a user clicks on a link on header of page.
How do I make sure the iframe is always on top of all content? CSS z-indexs don't work effectively in this case.

Answer (score 4):

`z-index` probably doesn't work because your `iframe` is [not a positioned box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index):

> For a positioned box, the 'z-index' property specifies:
>
> 1. The stack level of the box in the current stacking context.
> 2. Whether the box establishes a local stacking context.

Set its `position` to something other than `static`.  For example:

```
iframe#myiframe {
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

z-index only works on positioned content. Either use *position:absolute;* and top/left/right to position the element or use *position:relative;* to leave the element where it is.

Either one should enable z-index on the element.

Comment: position: absolute; doesn't need top/bottom/left/right.  If they are not specified, the box stays put and does not affect the box model (i.e. it stays on top of non-absolute things).  Same with relative.

Comment: /smackhead   Good point. Somehow I always automatically applied those values, assuming a default of 0 on top/left. Learn something new every day.